# Select all CheckBoxes in CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have a `CheckBox` and a `CheckBox` list on my web page.
If the `CheckBox` is selected, all the `CheckBoxes` in the `CheckBoxList` should get selected, and if the `CheckBox` is unchecked, similarly all the `CheckBoxes` in the `CheckBox` should get deselected (unchecked).

**.aspx code**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
            <asp:ListItem>Item A</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item B</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item C</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item D</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item E</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item F</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Item G</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:CheckBox ID="allChkBox" Text="Select all" runat="server" 
                oncheckedchanged="allChkBox_CheckedChanged" />
```

I tried by doing somehting like this, but it didb't work:

```
bool prevSelection = false;
protected void allChkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if (!prevSelection)
        {
            foreach (ListItem chkitem in CheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                chkitem.Selected = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (ListItem chkitem in CheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                chkitem.Selected = false;
            }
        }
        prevSelection = !prevSelection;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your aspx code?

Comment: Ok.. others provided answers. I would suggest .. you should do this in client javascript and no need postback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use client script for something like this so your page doesnt have to do a postback

If that is a possibility try firing a javascript function on click to do the looping and selecting ... something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
checked=false;
function checkedAll (frm1) {
    var aa= document.getElementById('frm1');
     if (checked == false)
          {
           checked = true
          }
        else
          {
          checked = false
          }
    for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++) 
    {
           if(aa.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') { 
             aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
           }
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Need to check html input type.. aa.elements[i].type == 'checkbox'

Comment: I was thinking to use a checkbox instead of a button click to check/uncheck all checkboxes. But, it looks like the `CheckBoxAll` doesn't have a client side functionality which can detect if the `CheckBox` has been unchecked/checked. Can it be done using a `checkbox` i.e if the `CheckBoxAll` is checked, it should automatically check all other check boxes.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've dabbled in ASP.NET, but your `prevSelection` field will be initialized to `false` on each and every request.  That value will not be persisted between requests.  So, you either need to store it in View State or the cache and load it from there in your event handler, or, even better, change your method to something like this:

```
protected void allChkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem chkitem in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        chkitem.Selected = allChkBox.Selected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this Iif I have understood the requirement right!)? This will make all items `selected` in a CheckBoxList control by default when it renders:

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Page.IsPostBack) return;
  LoadCountryList();
}


private void LoadCountryList()
{
  _ctx = new PayLinxDataContext();

  chkCountries.DataSource = _ctx.Countries.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
  chkCountries.DataBind();

  foreach (ListItem item in chkCountries.Items)
  {
    item.Selected = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a variable outside the function, how about using the checkbox itself:

```
protected void allChkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkbox = sender;

    foreach (ListItem chkitem in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        chkitem.Selected = chkbox.Selected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with linq like this

```
var allChecked = (from ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items 
                              where item.Selected 
                              select int.Parse(item.Value)).ToList();


  var all = (from ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items 

                                  select int.Parse(item.Value)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function CheckUnCheckAll()
    {
        var list = document.getElementById("<%=DataList1.ClientID%>") ;
        var chklist = list.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i=0;i<chklist.length;i++)
        {
            if (chklist[i].type=="checkbox" )
            {
                chklist[i].checked = checkoruncheck;
            }
        } 
    }
```